# which tags needs to be use to create email template for outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am working on email template for outlook 2013. I have this code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td height="1" style="mso-line-height-alt:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px; margin: 0; color: rgb(215, 139, 41); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(215, 139, 41); text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; border-left: 15px solid rgb(215, 139, 41); font-size: 20px;">Accolades</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

which is looks good in browser like bellow image [image]

But it look like bellow image in outlook[image]

Extra space is added above content. I am using plane table elements.

This is happen for image also but on right side. Extra space added in outlook at image right side like above image:
 [image]

How to fix this problem? Suggestion to create good email template for outlook 2013 is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please add a relevant code. 1st: missing font definition. 2nd: no chance to know what element has margin or padding and cause the blank space.

Comment: @panther 1st: the problem is not about font size, the problem is in height which is get increased in outlook. 2nd: I am using table element only like <tr><td><img..></td><td><span></span></td></tr> I am not applying any margin or padding for this.

Comment: fine, no additional infos, impossible to answer. Good luck.

Comment: @Pooja presumably because Outlook recognises MSO style properties while the browsers don't.